# How to show inprogress message on module installation node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing vs code extension locally using nodejs.I am trying to show inprogress message on mudule installing time but i do not know how to do it.I got some code from google but i do not know how to use it.please help me anyone.How to implement that code in my script.

My code:

```
var module = "c://MAMP/htdocs/listofmodules/module.tgz";
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
var child = exec("npm install --save module,
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    showError('stdout: ' + stdout);
    showError('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
       showError('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Got some script by searching:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function(err) { 

npm.on('log', function(message) {
// log installation progress
console.log(message);
});
});
```

and

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execSync("npm install ffi",{stdio:[0,1,2]});
```

and

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
child = exec('npm install ffi').stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```